# Is the full-height newel post for this oak railing structural?

Tags: load-bearing

There is a railing between the kitchen and a sunken living room. I really dont think the post is structural since its a.)just an oak post b.)looks nailed in with finish nails. I just wanted a second opinion.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is underneath? Slab, basement, crawlspace? Have you looked in the attic?

Comment: @mikeazo Underneath is just open crawl space, above if a beam that spans the full length to connect to another wall to support the bedroom above. I added another photo to show

Comment: your picture is unclear .... can you slide a piece of paper between the post and the ceiling (even a little bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly not structural. Posts like that never are unless they've been installed by someone with no training or guidance. This seems to be a modern home, which makes it even more unlikely that it's structural. Depending on the home layout, there's a probably a beam or girder truss inside the corner passing over the post.

That said, I'm looking through a peephole from the other side of the internet. The question is not answerable with certainty. Get some local help and provide appropriate access to the attic or other areas of the building.